# Websocket with Redux, message request, message response is received always in order?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, websocket, socket.io, redux

Suppose I edit my profile name, in order "Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie"

Then the response message is always in order?

Is there no situation that "Alpha" would be a last response message so that my profile name is edited to "Alpha" in the end?

Redux)

For example, I'm using Redux in my application.

In Redux App, I will dispatch EDIT_PROFILE_REQUEST action with (socket.send) three times which has a payload of profile name , "Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie" in order.

Then if the edit process is done, EDIT_PROFILE_SUCCESS action will be dispatched.

The part I'm wondering is EDIT_PROFILE_SUCCESS is also received in order , "Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie". ?

Can I guarantee always response message also be in order, so that my profile name will be edited to "Charlie"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

TL;DR -> You cannot gaurantee that the 3rd party socket service deliver's you messages in that order. But, for the most part, you can engineer the javascript application to behave as though it were a guarantee.

If you're using `socket.send`, I'll assume that's a 3rd party websocket service like socket.io. In that case, *you're communicating from your js client*, managing internal data "state" with redux, *to another computer*, the websocket server.

The behavior of the websocket is **outside the boundary** of your javascript client. Even if the service thinks it will respond in order, the real world can intervene... power might go out in between the (A), (B), and (C) requests. Then A is accepted and responded too, and same with (C), but the websocket server never saw (B).

That's an extreme, but illustrative example.

Redux can help drive a couple guaranties or safe assumptions if it's implemented appropriately. It can help ensure that the order with which your js app's 'state' or data changes, is synchronous, i.e. if you do (a) then (b) then (c) only within the javascript application, they happen in that order in time.

The key then is managing that boundary. You manage the boundary of a user clicking your js app by waiting for the click, after a user has decided to click a button. In the same way, you can wait for confirmation from the websocket that it did do (A) (B) or (C).

A naive, but very useful pattern for your example would be to make your js application behave as if the order were guaranteed, with a 'take the latest request' approach. If you fire off socket.send(A), you wait for a response. If (B) is sent before the socket says it's gotten (A), you throw away (A) and send (B), and wait to see if the socket replies that the (B) operation was successful.

Comment: Thank you, how about using 'sequence number' concept to guarantee the order? Thank you again! If there are some resources of this problem. let me know please. ! Is there another solution?

Comment: As simple as it seems, this problem is one of the most challenging and most fun problems in CS... distributed computing. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9dALrnCOLNE does a nice job of explaining how some seemingly simple 'order problems' become incredibly complex, and can be solved.In practice though, using redux on a javascript client, there are much more straight forward and practical ways of "guaranteeing order".  Do you have a particular problem, bug, or use case in mind?

Comment: The practical way of making sure that after 3 edits you don't end up back at "Alpha" is to not fire off the "EDIT_SUCCESS" style action that would change the name on the JS app to "Alpha" unless that was the last "EDIT_REQUEST" that got sent. I.e. if you sent an EDIT_REQUEST for Beta, after the Alpha, and got a successful BETA change from the websocket, you stop waiting for the alpha success and ignore it.